# assistance with optimization

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, optimization

not sure if stackoverflow is normally used for stuff like this but i'm looking for assistance in optimizing my code. I am running a method to query a count from a database which is fast and works fine. and a timer that is set to run this every 5 minutes. When i implement the timer in my main window after initialization it freezes when opening the window for 30+ seconds. It didn't do that before I added the timers. Any help optimizing this or tips on improving the way this works would be great!

Method that runs SQL query:

```
public string SQLDataTotalCalls()
        {
            DateTime dte = DateTime.Today;

            string fixedStartDate = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd " + "05:00:00.000" + "}", dte);
            string fixedEndDate = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd " + "05:00:00.000" + "}", dte.AddDays(1));

            SqlConnection connection = null;

            using (connection)
            {
                try
                {
                    var dataSet = new DataSet();

                    connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=QL1OADB1;Initial Catalog=OADB;User Id=;Password=");
                    connection.Open();

                    var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(SOURCEID) AS 'MYCOUNT' "
                                                 + "FROM [OADB].[oadb].[CmsCallHistory] "
                                                 + "WHERE disposition = 2 and DISPSPLIT in (" + SkillNumber + ") AND SEGSTOP BETWEEN '" + fixedStartDate + "' and '" + fixedEndDate + "'",
                        connection)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    };

                    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = command };

                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

                    return dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MYCOUNT"].ToString();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Timer that triggers the method every 5 minutes:

```
public async Task RunPeriodicQueryTotalCalls()
        {
            TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(interval);

                string result = await Task.Run((Func<string>)SQLDataTotalCalls);

                TotalDailyCalls = result;
            }
        }
```

This is where i initialize the window. please note that I run these querys also when the application first launches before the timer runs otherwise the numbers will not post until it runs 5 minutes later:

```
public ScoreBoardBigViewWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();            

            string value = "Enter Skill Number Here";
            if (Tmp.InputBox("New document", "New document name:", ref value) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                SkillNumber = value;
            }

            TotalDailyLast7Days = SQLDataSevenPastCalls();
            TotalDailyCalls = SQLDataTotalCalls();
            TotalDailyAbandon = SQLDataAbandonCalls();           

            RunPeriodicQueryTotalCalls();
            RunPeriodicQueryAbandonCalls();
        }
```

If i remove RunPeriodicQueryTotalCalls(); and RunPeriodicQueryAbandonCalls(); then the performance issue goes away.

If stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this type of question please let me know and I'll reach out to other avenues for further assistance.

Comment: You should look in to using parameters for your SQL queries not only does it make your code safer it gives you a small performance boost because it can use cached query plans.

Comment: Thanks! i'll look into that now as an option of something to implement.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Try posting on Code Review.